# CKEditor crashes when switching text format for specific content types

Tags: wysiwyg

drupal 7.38

wysiwyg 7.x-2.2+63-dev

CKEditor 4.5.1.a513a92

If I create an article, switch text formats, everything is fine.

If I create a basic page, switch text formats, the ckeditor toolbar crashes and none of the buttons are clickable.

The crash also occurs if I create a new content type.

Here is a copy of the console log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sas' of undefined
>   js_ALIKtebL-PsIulJhUegpZmaxTRnPdAyakIc8kMeoL-4.js:382 Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'sas' of
>   undefinedDrupal.wysiwyg.plugins.sas.attach @
>   js_ALIKtebL-PsIulJhUegpZmaxTRnPdAyakIc8kMeoL-4.js:382(anonymous
>   function) @
>   js_ALIKtebL-PsIulJhUegpZmaxTRnPdAyakIc8kMeoL-4.js:103CKEDITOR.tools.createClass.proto.setData
>   @ ckeditor.js?nstvdm:780(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js?nstvdm:349j
>   @ ckeditor.js?nstvdm:10CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:12CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:13CKEDITOR.tools.extend.setData @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:251b @ ckeditor.js?nstvdm:775(anonymous function) @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:777CKEDITOR.editor.setMode @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:328(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js?nstvdm:323j @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:10CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:12CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:13CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fireOnce @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:12CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fireOnce @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:13(anonymous function) @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:246CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load.g @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:226CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:226(anonymous function) @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:245(anonymous function) @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:233(anonymous function) @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:231CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load.g @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:226CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load.B @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:226CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load.s @
>   ckeditor.js?nstvdm:226(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js?nstvdm:227

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report for a contributed module. Please report all bugs to the module's issue queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would "downgrade" to the stable [WYSIWYG 7.x-2.2](https://www.drupal.org/node/1801458) version of the WYSIWYG module, and to the 3.6.x version of CKEditor (such as CKEditor version 3.6.6.1.7696), since the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module does not support the 4.x version yet ...).

Another option is to switch to the [CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module (which is in core in D8 now ...), and no longer use the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module in combination with the CKEditor library.